# How to set DIC parameter that user provided through ContainerAwareCommand?

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to set Container parameter in ContainerAwareCommand like `$this->getContainer()->setParameter('host', $host);`?

Because below code:

```
class ServerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $helper = $this->getHelper('question');
        $question1 = new Question('Provide a hostname: ', 'localhost');
        $host = $helper->ask($input, $output, $question1);

        $this->getContainer()->setParameter('host', $host);
```

give me DependencyInjection\Exception\LogicException:

> Impossible to call set() on a frozen ParameterBag.

Comment: Basically no.  Containers are actually "compilied" with the final results showing up under var/cache.  Cannot change interactively.

Comment: @Cerad ok, that was stupid. I need these parameters to be written in parameters.yml if I want to use it in controller. Console parameters can't be kept without persist it in file or db. Right?

Comment: Correct.  You could have your command actually update the parameters.yml file using the yaml component.  I suppose.